# Do categorical fields need indexing? (MySQL or MongoDB)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, indexing

For a table(let's say 'food'), there is a column 'type' with potential value [1,2,3,4] that specifies the type of that entry (e.g. fruit). As I expect selection like

```
SELECT name FROM food WHERE type = 3 ;
```

would be called most often, I wonder would an index be recommended in this case. Since there is only a few values possible for that field I wonder if the index would be useful.(Similarly for MongoDB?)

Comment: It depends on what other queries are being run against it and the schema of the document and the size of the document on disk and whether this server has ssds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index on such a field is likely not to be useful in MySQL.  Actually, such an index could make most queries worse.

There is a case where an index will always be faster.  This is a query that *only* uses columns in the index, such as:

```
select count(type)
from food
where type = 3;
```

This is faster because reading the index should be faster than reading the table, because the data is smaller (presumably, you could include all columns in the index).

In other cases, MySQL uses an index for a table when it is available.

The question you are asking is about the "selectivity" of an index.  Consider your query:

```
SELECT name
FROM food
WHERE type = 3 ;
```

If all rows have `type = 3`, then you have to read all the matching records anyway (to get the value of `name`).  If there is one record per page, then the index is probably helping you, because it reduces the number of page reads.  A more realistic situation would have a page contain 100 records.  Then, if 25% of the records have the same type, a typical page would have 25 such records on it.  Basically, every page still has to be read.  The question is whether the pages are read sequentially (a "full table scan") or through the index.

There is a difference between these two ways of reading a table.  In the full table scan, the pages are read sequentially and once a page is read, it is not accessed again.  In the index read, the pages are read randomly, one record at a time, and a page could be read multiple times.  In the extreme case, the pages don't fit in the page cache and the same page is flushed to disk and read again and again for each record on the page.  Highly inefficient.

You can make this query more efficient by having an index on `type, name`.

So, the answer to your question is to be careful about indexes, especially with large tables.  When you do have an index on a categorical column, make it a composite index so your queries can be satisfied only using the index and not having to go back to the data pages.

Comment: Oh nvm realised this is a MySQL answer, misread the question as primarily MongoDB

Comment: @Sammaye . . . I think you were right.  I updated the answer to (hopefully) better express what I wanted to say.

Comment: Yeah that's better, it applies similarly for MongoDB in that case as well

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I read somewhere else that the position of a column may actually have influence on performance, in this case would it be better to place the 'type' column right after the primary id column? Also, if my actual select would be selecting for many columns like select name, price, calorie from FROM food WHERE type = 3; what should the index be then? I guess the index should not contain too many fields?

Comment: The ordering of columns makes a big, big difference in indexes.  MySQL documentation actually does a good job of explaining this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  In particular, columns *after* the `id` are not going to be used for anything other than their values.  In other words, you want the `id` to be last, not first.

Answer (score 2):

Having the index is unlikely to help, but you should test it with your queries and your data. If the column has few distinct values queries will return a sizeable portion of the table's rows, and reading the index is equivalent to a full table scan. In fact, a full table scan might even be faster than reading the index.

If the type of the row is used in other queries it may help to have the type as a part of a multi column index.